# How to get Hot Rod client's statistics?

Tags: java, infinispan

I'm using Hot Rod Java client for communicating with Infinispan Remote Cache.
How can I get the client's statistics regarding cache usage (hits, misses etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain statistics for a remote cache use https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/14.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/RemoteCache.html#clientStatistics()

Comment: is it possible to enable this MXBean via config file (hotrod-client.properties)?

Comment: Use the `infinispan.client.hotrod.jmx=true` property as described in the javadocs https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/14.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/configuration/package-summary.html